# Forward requester ID from Pi-hole to Unbound

Tags: dns, unbound, pihole

I have a running Pi-hole and an Unbound DNS set up in my local network. The Pi-hole is only responsible for blocking (I know unbound can also do this) and the unbound does resolving an caching. I also have some metrics attached to the unbound to visualize the logged data.

Currently all requests are logged as 127.0.0.1 because they are forwarded from the Pi-hole.
Is it possible to configure the Pi-hole to forward the local requester ID to the Unbound so that it gets logged?